# PyTest produces warning DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-asyncio

I have added pytest-asyncio to my poetry test and dev groups with the following code:

```py
    async def blah():
        return 1
    
    
    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_me(mock_client, mock_config, event_loop):
        res = await blah()
        assert 1 == res
```

When I `run poetry run pytest` I get this warning:

```
/Users/ykhaburzaniya/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/alakazam-6HJyiZWL-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytest_asyncio/plugin.py:884: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
    _loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

In my poetry.lock I have pytest-asyncio version = "0.23.3".

What can I do to get rid of this warning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytest: runtimeerror there is no current event loop in thread 'mainthread'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66583461/pytest-runtimeerror-there-is-no-current-event-loop-in-thread-mainthread)